# What Should be the ideal sequence to Learn Programming languages to become professional developer

Tags: web-development, database, language

I am  new in programming i haven't learn any programming language yet.
i have some basic knowledge of HTML and CSS and C++ can you please suggest me which language should be master in , to become a professional web developer and please suggest me the sequence which language to go first and so on.

I want to develop a website that is responsive interactive and people can sign up to access premium content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is a programming language, even if it isn't commonly used in Web development ;)

Building a Web site generally involves two parts - the server side (aka the back end), and the client side (the browser, aka the front end).  For *my* Web development work, I generally use PHP and MySQL on the server, and Javascript with HTML and CSS on the browser.  To get up to speed with *my* code, in addition to learning the HTML markup language and CSS (a presentation language), you would need to come up to speed with *three* other programming languages - PHP, SQL, and Javascript.  For most serious Web projects, you're going to find a similar level of effort is required.

My suggestion is you get a good *current* book or three, and work through the exercises.  For the back end work, [PHP and MySQL Web Development (5th Edition)](http://amzn.to/2uoNIIz) could be a good starting point.  A good combination book for the client side work would be [Sams Teach Yourself HTML, CSS and JavaScript All in One](http://amzn.to/2v2z07B) which covers HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript (including jQuery).  As far as responsive Web design, you might want to consider [Learning Responsive Web Design: A Beginner's Guide](http://amzn.to/2t154HS) or [Sams Teach Yourself Responsive Web Design in 24 Hours](http://amzn.to/2vnagXa).  In addition to learning the programming languages, you are going to want to learn good design principles, but that's another question...

Note that the "24 hours" of the Sams Teach Yourself series is not a single 24 hour day, but rather 24 hours of programming lessons, each an hour long - so you need to plan to spend at least a few days working through them.

**TL;DR**

When I started doing Web development, HTML was pretty much all there was to work with, even having a database for your site was an expensive option from the hosting company.  Along came PHP, and I got a Sams Teach Yourself book about PHP, which greatly eased the pain of building Web sites.  I found the format easy to work with where learning came in bite-sized chunks.  Some time later, MySQL came along, and I got more books about working with PHP and MySQL together.  I think it was Javascript that showed up next, but it wasn't very widely supported, and browser support was *very* inconsistent.  (There are those who *still* swear at micro$^^t for their incompatibilities...)  Again, more books helped, although initially I only used Javascript for "cute" features such as making snow fall down a page, tugged by the cursor position, because the unreliable support made it difficult to use for serious projects.  When CSS was introduced, it was another set of headaches due to differing feature sets and interpretations, and again I stuck to "the old ways" to keep my sites working consistently.  The time came, though, that CSS became more common than not, and to move my work forward, I bought more books.  Now we've got HTML5, CSS3, and Web sites have to work on a *lot* more systems than just desktops with ever-increasing resolutions - so what am I doing?  Buying more books...

Books are your friends.  Get some, and learn to love them.